# select unique values and it's corresponding values in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this :

[image]

Is there a way in dplyr to select the first observation of each group of weeknum and it's correpsonding date i know how to get the unique values but i don't know how to get their corresponding dates
if you could help I would appreciate it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice_head` after grouping by the 'weeknum'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(weeknum) %>%
   slice_head(n = 1)
```

Or with `distinct`

```
df1 %>%
     distinct(weeknum, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

---

In `base R`, it can be done with `duplicated` and `subset`

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(weeknum))
```

Comment: thanks i'm so stupid, i tried the distinct 10 mins ago and it did not work, it works now

Comment: @Blueberry May be you used only `distinct(weeknum)`, then it returns that column unique rows only, as `.keep_all = FALSE` by default

Comment: i had a left_join and a mutate before, those two columns came from another table, anyways thanks for confirming that distinct works just fine :)